Firebase App Check doesn't work in debug mode
Trying to run my Android app (emulator) in debug mode using Firebase App Check. I turned RTDB as Enforsed with added SHA-256 of my Android debug-key. I also added App-check debug token (taken from app logs) to Firebase App Check console. But I still can't get data from RTDB. There are no Firebase errors in the logs. So what the issue?
I run App-check init code in Android app class onCreate callback:
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance().installAppCheckProviderFactory(
            BuildConfig.DEBUG ?
                    DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance() :
                    PlayIntegrityAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance(), true);

App-check libs:
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity:18.0.0'

Also I operate in Firebase console as Editor, not Owner.
